# How can I set my favicon to appear on every page of my website without using JS/PHP

Tags: html, favicon

Im new to HTML/CSS and have just created a favicon by copy and pasting code from a favicon generator website.

The following is the code ive placed in my `index.html`

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

I want my favicon to appear on the other pages on my website. I'm wondering if I am forced to copy and paste all that code over and over again on each page or if there is a cleaner way to accomplish that (without using JS/PHP, which I am unfamiliar with).

Thank you

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong. You have a bunch of HTML files, access each one individually and want all them to show the same favicon?

Comment: @Alyson That's correct

Comment: create a favicon.ico, place it on the root and by default the browser will look for it even if you don't explicitly say it.

Comment: @Ibu that is currently my setup and that doesn't seem to be the case with Chrome

Comment: @Ibu is correct, dropping a favicon.ico in your root directory should cover most of your needs with no effort. To find out why it does not work, you should check Chrome network logs (is there a 404 error ? Does Chrome even try to load the icon ? Etc). You could also try with another browser just to make sure you are not facing a caching issue (Chrome has visited your site many times and may consider it already knows there is no favicon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunaly, the favicon must be explicit in your HTML file.
As you're using pure HTML, yes, you'll need to copy and paste in each file.